# jekyll contact page on nav bar keeps redirect to 404 page

Tags: jekyll

Sorry, I'm new to Jekyll. I am using the Beautiful Jekyll theme at https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll

On the navigation bar, both "about me" and "contact" redirects to the 404.html page.

In _config.yml, I see the following

```
# List of links in the navigation bar
navbar-links:
  Home: ""
  About Me: "about"
  Contact: "contact"
```

and in my root directory, I do see a **about.md** and **contact.md**

about.md

```
---
layout: page
title: About
---

# Hello World
```

contact.md

```
---
layout: page
title: Contact
---

# Contact Page
```

What should I fix here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're certainly using a project repository situated at `github.com/UserName/RepositoryName`, served at `UserName.github.io/RepositoryName`.

In `_config.yml` you need to set `baseurl: /RepositoryName`.

Comment: thanks, that seems to do the trick. But is there any reason you can think of why the CSS isn't rendering on these two pages?

Comment: If you're ok with my answer, you can approve it and ask another question about how your theme is managing css.